# How to extract the url in text box with imacro

Tags: imacros

can anyone help me with a imacro script to extract the url from a webpage which is in text box

For example i want to extract this url `http://myhost.com/blogs/trackback?post_id=1` from following page(source code)

```
<div id="section-trackbacks" class="blog-section tab_container">
    <h3 class="section-title"><span>Trackbacks</span></h3>  
    <div class="trackback-container">
        <div class="entry-trackback" onclick="eblog.trackback.url.copy();">Trackback URL for this blog entry</div>
        <div class="entry-trackback-input">
            <input type="text" class="inputbox ffa fwb fsg" id="trackback-url" value="http://myhost.com/blogs/trackback?post_id=1" style="width: 90%;" onclick="eblog.trackback.url.copy();" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
tag pos=1 type=input attr=class:inputbox<sp>ffa<sp>fwb<sp>fsg extract=htm
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var index=s.indexOf(\"value=\");var index2=s.indexOf(\"style\");var r=s.substring(index+7,index2-2);r;")
prompt {{!var1}}
```